# How do I can to call ts-error by condition

Tags: typescript

I have react component with props:

```
type List = {
  id: number;
  [x: string]: any;
};

type Props = {
  list: List[] | undefined;
  titleKey: string;
};
```

**Q1**: How I can check what value of `titleKey` exist in all List items?

**Q2**: How call ts-error if `titleKey` not exist in one List item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need one property to depend on another in the same type. That means you need `Props` to be generic.

```
type Props<T extends List> = {
  list: T[] | undefined;
  titleKey: keyof T;
};
```

Now props accepts some type `T`, which must be a subtype of `List`. And whatever that type is, `titleKey` must be a property name in that type.

Example usage of this type:

```
type PropsTestA = Props<{ id: number, foo: string }>
/* yields this type:
{
    list: {
        id: number;
        foo: string;
    }[] | undefined;
    titleKey: "id" | "foo";
}
*/
```

---

Now to use generic props, your component must be generic too. It just needs to forward the type to those props.

```
function Foo<T extends List>(props: Props<T>) {
    return <></>
}
```

And now everything works like you expect:

```
// works
const testA = <Foo
  list={[{ id: 123, name: 'First Item'}]}
  titleKey='name'
/>

// type error
const testB = <Foo
  list={[{ id: 123, name: 'First Item'}]}
  titleKey='badkey' // Type '"badkey"' is not assignable to type '"id" | "name"'.(2322)
/>
```

[link to working Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.2&ssl=8&ssc=13&pln=8&pc=12#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChSYBPMJOAGWAGd4BeOAb1LjmABMAuOADsAriABGSKAG4ucANoAPQcyjAhAcwC6glEMqyAvrIrVaABRxhGAHgAqcJIphIhvRvSYwAfHDaduABsvQTt5LTgAHzgRNyRMdSReWW4YYBhApABpJEpBAGtciEw4OyMTKho4SwhrOyRmAEE-aqtbdh4BYTFJKAAaOEwICBUYNU04Q29SAHoAKlIA7jhg5kEl5eW+QVEJKRTN5aGRuFV1DQPuQ3ComLiEoSTLuDSM7NzBACI+T9vP48+RlIcxm5EwsQwwAgQjgADFhvZHM5XO5PMxvAAKMBtQQ1az2bwASg4cm4RBgIigMJs3hsM2mhnIMxmcAA7tB8oxSGhocwXg0YM02DZ4RA5KsYCx2PJSRxOoIAIwAJgAzAMhCgQEhBPhYcAoHyAJIuED4RncLTml7pTI5SgsfAarVkelMlmVWhSHBQbm8+AuZgAIRaIuG4q8Uplmw62zgyrVwk12oIeoN8GNSFNVstclettyDvEKF4hUo+DgzNKZgInyLJdyn3LTGEEHgKEYjGAGg14kyLwgL2r+G+vF+0U+TqQjYAdBjVUqlYTZt4gA)